# Returning `number|string` into a `number` variable

Tags: typescript

I have the below rather simplistic typescript code to better understand the language.

Now, quite obviously to more advanced users, this.dId throws `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'` due to the return types of `get_value_from_input` `number|string` and the type of `this.dId:number`.

If I make `dId:number|string` it obviously works but I don't want dId to be a string.

What is the **correct** way to execute this in typescript?

I want to persist `dId` as a number and `name` as a string while allowing a generalized DOM accessor that can pull by ID.

Of course I could make 1 function per return type but it is unclear if that's why typescript would require or if there is a more elegant way to do this?

```
class Submission{

    dId:number; //issue
    eId:number; //issue

    name:string; //issue
    

    constructor(){
        //These throw: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'
        this.dId =  get_value_from_input("dId");
        this.eId =  get_value_from_input("eId");

        this.name =  get_value_from_input("name");


    }
    

}


function get_value_from_input(id:string):number|string{
       if(id=="1"){
         return 1;
       }else{
         return "foo";
       }

}
```

Comment: The `value` of an `HTMLInputElement` is always a `string`, never a `number`.  Not sure why you're widening the annotated return type to `number | string`.  I'd suggest leaving it as `string` and then [converting it to a number at runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) in situations where you know it's going to be a number, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6vzDw) shows. Does that answer your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. For pedagogical purposes, what if your `function f(){}` could return either a number or a string? What would you do in TS?

Comment: @jcalz I updated my Q to represent what I am trying to understnad.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you expect to happen, because how can `"foo"` be assigned to a `number`?

Comment: @CherryDT My goal is to express a function that can return a `number` or a `string` based on different scenarios. Is this able to be handled in typscript? Eg what variable type do I return this into. if the variable is a `string` or `number` this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Then you would need an explicit conversion or an explicit type check before you assign to the final variable. Because, again, the whole point of TypeScript is to prevent you from doing exactly this, trying to assign `"foo"` to a `number` for instance. What if your HTML suddenly has a field `<input id="dId" type="text" value="hello world">`, for example due to a bug in your templates? The compiler would have failed its job there if it would just let you do that assignment.

Comment: @CherryDT thanks. Please do keep in mind I am just starting to learn TS. This may fall under the "dumb question" category but I'm strictly learning.

Comment: I really need to know more about this `get_value_from_input()` function.  Is there any hope that the *compiler* could know whether the function returns a `number` or a `string` given the input?  If not, then the best you can do is either a runtime coercion or a compile time assertion, both shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2MrW), and they both have weird behavior.  What do you want to do when you're wrong about your prediction?  Do you want a runtime error or do you want a possibly weird runtime value?

Comment: If you have some way of actually predicting the output type from the input type then tell us.  Anyway, what should I be doing here with answering the question?  My point of writing these comments is to make sure the answer addresses the question totally before writing it, not necessarily to have a chat about TS in general.  So followup questions belong in their own post.  How, specifically should we proceed here?  (Remember to @jcalz notify me or I might not see a response)

Comment: @jcalz is there anything philosophically wrong about declaring my variables as `string | number` if I don't know what they'll be in this scenario? This feels as if it isn't really the point of TS.

Comment: If you don't know what they'll be then `string | number` is fine, but then you have to handle it. I showed two ways (runtime conversion, compile time assertion) of handling it, along with the consequences of the assumptions being wrong.  At this point, though, I might have to disengage, since we've gone back and forth several times and I don't know if I'm any closer to knowing what you're looking for.  If you think any of my previous code links are helpful, tell me which one and I'll write it up in an answer with an explanation. Let me know!

Comment: @jcalz thanks I think I am pretty good at his point and appreciate the input!